# Get only one document of each user - mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I m stuck with a mongo aggregate query. Right now I have a collection which contains posts of various users (whose details are present in users collection).

I need a query to fetch only one post of each user (like group by in SQL)

**POSTS collection data**

```
{
  language:'english',
  status:'A',
  desc:'Hi there',
  userId:'5b891370f43fe3302bbd8918'
},{
  language:'english',
  status:'A',
  desc:'Hi there - 2'
  userId:'5b891370f43fe3302bbd8918'
},{
  language:'english',
  status:'A',
  desc:'Hi there - 3'
  userId:'5b891370f43fe3302bbd8001'
}
```

**Here is my query**

```
db.col('posts').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            language: 'english',
            status: "A"
        }
    }, {
        $sample: { size: 10 }
    }, {
        $sort: { _id: -1 }
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'userId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'ownerData'
        }
    }], (err, data) => { console.log(err,data) });
```

**Desired Output**

```
   {
      language:'english',
      status:'A',
      desc:'Hi there',
      userId:'5b891370f43fe3302bbd8918',
      ownerData:[[object]]
    },{
      language:'english',
      status:'A',
      desc:'Hi there - 3'
      userId:'5b891370f43fe3302bbd8001',
      ownerData:[[object]]
    }
```

Comment: group by user, and fetch the first element of every group

Answer (score 3):

**$group**: will as group by of mysql. **$first**: will take  first element of collection field from group. **$lookup** acts as join in mysql.

```
db.tempdate.aggregate([ 
    { $group : 
        { 
          _id : "$userId", 
          language : { $first: '$language' }, 
          status : { $first: '$status' },  
          desc : { $first: '$desc' } 
        } 
     },
     { $lookup: 
        { 
            from: "user", 
            localField: "_id", 
            foreignField: "user_id",
            as: "userData" 
         } 
     }
 ]).pretty();`

Output

`{
    "_id" : "5b891370f43fe3302bbd8001",
    "language" : "english",
    "status" : "A",
    "desc" : "Hi there - 3",
    "userData" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3633a12b8613823f3056e"),
            "user_id" : "5b891370f43fe3302bbd8001",
            "name" : "Bhuwan"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "5b891370f43fe3302bbd8918",
    "language" : "english",
    "status" : "A",
    "desc" : "Hi there",
    "userData" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3634612b8613823f3056f"),
            "user_id" : "5b891370f43fe3302bbd8918",
            "name" : "Harry"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation stage for the distinct `userId` and then use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get users data.

```
db.col('posts').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "language": 'english', "status": "A" }},
  { "$sample": { "size": 10 }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": -1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$userId",
    "language": { "$first": "$language" },
    "status": { "$first": "$status" },
    "desc": { "$first": "$desc" }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "ownerData"
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use `group` and `$last`

```
db.getCollection('posts').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "language": 'english', "status": "A" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$userId",
     "primaryId" : { "$last": "$_id" },
    "language": { "$last": "$language" },
    "status": { "$last": "$status" },
    "desc": { "$last": "$desc" }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "ownerData"
  }},
  { $unwind:{path: '$ownerData',preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true} //to convert ownerData to json object
}
])
```